# What happens if Combat Celebrant is killed during combat?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What happens if [Combat Celebrant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCombat%20Celebrant%5d) attacks and is killed by blockers? Would the second combat phase still happen?

Comment: Is it really a duplicate? The triggered ability on Combat Celebrant will in any case resolve before it is killed.

Comment: Then the fact that it dies is even less relevant...

Comment: @MichałPolitowski I agree. The other question is about if an ability resolves if the source is removed. This question is about an ability that has already resolved, and if that ability has lasting effects afterwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the second combat phase will still happen.

Abilities are completely separate from the source of the ability.

> 112.7a Once activated or triggered, an ability exists on the stack independently of its source. Destruction or removal of the source after that time won’t affect the ability.

In this case, Combat Celebrant has a triggered ability that causes the additional combat step. Once that ability triggers (upon exerting it), that ability is completely separate from the Celebrant itself.